# How to coherently combine 3D and contour plots with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Both contour and 3d plots can be done easily in pgfplots, but I have a hard time combining them nicely.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve ([from the matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#contour-plots)):
[image: plot]

Comment: “Both contour and 3d plots can be done easily in pgfplots”: [Let us see that!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) What did you try to combine them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pgfplots can compute the z contours by means of gnuplot and its `contour gnuplot` interface.

The projection onto the x axis (i.e. with fixed y) can be done by means of a matrix line plot in which you replace the y coordinate of the input matrix by some fixed constant.

The projection onto the y axis (i.e. with fixed x) is more involved (at least if `mesh/ordering=x varies` as in my example below) because one needs to transpose the input matrix. In my example below, I simply replaced the meaning of x and y to achieve the transposal. This, of course, would be more involved for a data matrix (and I think that pgfplots has no builtin to do it).

Here is what I got so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y=0:2*pi,
]

    \newcommand\expr[2]{exp(-#1^2) * sin(deg(#2))}

    \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot={
            % cdata should not be affected by z filter:
            output point meta=rawz,
            number=10,
            labels=false,
        },
        samples=41,
        z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{-1.6},
    ]
        {\expr{x}{y}};

    \addplot3[
        samples=41,
        samples y=10,
        domain=0:2*pi,
        domain y=-2:2,
        % we want 1d (!) individually colored mesh segments:
        mesh, patch type=line,
        x filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{-2.5},
    ] 
        (y,x,{\expr{y}{x}});

    \addplot3[
        samples=41,
        samples y=10,
        % we want 1d (!) individually colored mesh segments:
        mesh, patch type=line,
        y filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{8},
    ] 
        {\expr{x}{y}};

    \addplot3[surf,samples=25]
        {\expr{x}{y}};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you see, the first contour is the z contour. It is computed using gnuplot (and requires the `-shell-escape` mechanism to this end!).

The x and y projections are computed using the same matrix of function values.  I chose a different sampling density to control how many "contour lines" shall be drawn. Note that these lines are conceptionally different from the z contours: they are already part of the sampling procedure and do not need to be computed externally. Note that I used `mesh, patch type=line` to tell pgfplots that (a) it should use individually colored segments and (b) it should not color the 2d structure, just the lines in scanline order (which is `mesh/ordering=x varies` in my case).

Comment: I found it suprisingly difficult to come from "contour plot" to "projection onto a line". I will think about a simpler solution which does not need these special distinctions.

Comment: Very clever to use the `plot3` to also make the side projections. (I can't compete with the master.) @ChristianFeuersanger: Do you plan to bring native contour plots to `pgfplots` or is it beyond the scope? If so, what algorithm would you use to implement it?

Comment: there is an experimental branch containing a native contour plot algorithm. However, it is unfinished so far and Nick Papior Andersen has not worked on it for some time. I will ask him. Concerning the contour gnuplot stuff: one can simply exchange the coordinates! That means there is a much simpler approach with `splot ... using 1:3:2` or something like that. I will think about a suitable pgfplots option.

Comment: I have implemented coherent support for this feature in pgfplots (by means of a key `contour dir=x|y|z`). It is currently part of the unstable (cf http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 14):

`pgfplot` supports contour plots by using the external-`gnuplot`. The side curves are obtained by two parametric curves. You can combine the 4 plots by putting all of them inside the `axis` environment.

The code is redundant, specially because the function in `gnuplot` (which does the contour) can not be passed from the tex code, as far as I know.

The result is the following:

[image: contourandsides]

The code follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-5:5]
\addplot3[domain=-5:5,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({x},{6.},{exp(-x*x - 0*0 + x*0. + 0.)});
\addplot3[domain=-5:5,samples=80,samples y=0,mark=none,black, opacity=0.5,thick]({-6.},{x},{exp(-0*0 - x*x + 0.*x + x)});
\addplot3 +[no markers,
    raw gnuplot,
  mesh=false,
    z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{-2}}
  ] gnuplot {
  set contour base;
  set cntrparam levels 20;
  unset surface;
  set view map;
  set isosamples 500;
  set samples 100;
  splot [-5:5][-5:5][0:1] exp(-x*x-y*y + x*y + y);
};
\end{axis}
\addplot3[surf,opacity=0.5,samples=40] {exp(-x*x-y*y + x*y + y)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on point 2? Can’t I just move the first `\addplot3` at the end of all `\addplot3`s? The `surf` plot is always on top? Nonetheless `opacity` should be included anyway to show hidden contour lines.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I was thinking in case one wants to change the view point, but you are right, this doesn't make sense for this application. I modified the code, but still left the `opacity` simply because that is what is shown in the example of the question. Admittedly the OP probably wants a fully automatic solution, but I don't know how to do that, I mention that in the new answer.

Answer (score 11):

here is a solution with `pst-solides3d` for the function z=sin(x)*sin(y), which can be adopted to your function.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\psset{arrowlength=3,arrowinset=0,viewpoint=50 30 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,
       lightsrc=viewpoint}

\begin{pspicture}(-7,-8)(7,8)
\axesIIID[linecolor=gray](0,0,0)(7,7,7)
\psSolid[ngrid=.3 .3,object=grille,base=1 8 1 8,
        linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=gray!50,action=draw]%

{\psset{object=courbe,r=0,linecolor=blue,resolution=360,function=Fxy}
\multido{\rA=0.0+1.0}{8}{%
  \defFunction[algebraic]{Fxy}(x){x}{0}{sin(x)*sin(\rA)+3}
  \psSolid[range=1 8]}
\multido{\rA=0.0+1.0}{8}{%
  \defFunction[algebraic]{Fxy}(y){0}{y}{sin(\rA)*sin(y)+3}
  \psSolid[range=1 8]}}
\psSurface[ngrid=.3 .3,fillcolor=green!30,incolor=gray!30,
  linewidth=0.4pt,algebraic](1,1)(8,8){ sin(x)*sin(y) +3 }

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same for a more complicated funktion:

[image]