# Contour plot of arbitrary R^3 function without gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a way to make pretty contour plots of arbitrary functions in R^3, like the one below for example, without the use of the gnuplot contour-stuff?

The reason I'm asking is I prefer a simple setup of the TeX environment, and since gnuplot isn't included in the Mactex bundle, and requires some adjustments to command line calls etc. I prefer to just solve things with what's available, if feasibly possible.

One obvious way would be to manually calculate the contours, but I saw this solution below and really liked that it took a single function for the surface and produced the contours on its own.

[image: Contour plot]

URL: [How to coherently combine 3D and contour plots with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87674/how-to-coherently-combine-3d-and-contour-plots-with-pgfplots)

Comment: Asymptote, which is included in the MacTeX bundle, has a module for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pgfplots` currently supports contour plots if they are either precomputed by means of some external program (`contour prepared`) or it can invoke an external tool to compute them as in `contour gnuplot`.

An implementation to compute the contours in TeX was attempted, but the contributor had to pursue his studies and could not finish it.

Means: No, this is currently impossible with `pgfplots`.

That means: `pgfplots` has to resort to `gnuplot` or "some other suitable external tool".

If someone would like to implement a contouring algorithm in, say, Lua, one could also integrate that.

Comment: Ok, I will make my own contour plots manually in pgfplots!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind the Python based matplotlib example [referred to above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87674/how-to-coherently-combine-3d-and-contour-plots-with-pgfplots) (note, there are more pleasant looking graphics [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html?highlight=contour#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.contourf)) then `sagetex` is an option since it allows you to run Python code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.savefig('Contour.png')
\end{sagesilent}
Sagetex let's you borrow the power of Python in creating pictures. This
example comes from:
\begin{verbatim}
http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots
\end{verbatim}
and it's running in \LaTeX \,with the power of the sagetex package.
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5in,height=4in]{Contour.png}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which gives this output when running on the [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com) site:
[image]