# Matplotlib symbols

Tags: symbols, matplotlib

I have recently drawn up a lot of plots in Python (`matplotlib`), but then I realized that I couldn't find their LaTeX equivalents.

I am specifically looking to generate circle, square, and diamond symbols which are half-filled (left, right, top or bottom).

For example I can generate filled and unfilled squares using `\backsquare` and `\Square` but cannot generate a partially filled one (filled left-, right-, top- half etc). I can do that for left- and right filled circles using `\LEFTcircle` and `\RIGHTcircle` but not for other symbols.

Comment: The `sagetex` package lets you work with matplotlib. See my answer to [Contour plot of arbitrary R^3 function without gnuplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159093/contour-plot-of-arbitrary-r3-function-without-gnuplot).

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to use any package in latex.

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsfonts}'
```