# Using output_dir with gnuplot fails to find .table file

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, auxiliary-files, shell-escape

I am not sure where the problem is, but using `gnuplot` as per the MWE below does not know about the `-output-directory=` option as I get

> Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{TeX-SE_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened.

So if you save the MWE as `TeX-SE.tex`, the following fails with the above error message:

```
mkdir tempfiles
pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=tempfiles TeX-SE.tex
```

but the following works fine

```
pdflatex -shell-escape  TeX-SE.tex
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{FunctionE}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{exp(-#1^2) * sin(deg(#2))}%
}

%% Following based on code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87674/how-to-coherently-combine-3d-and-contour-plots-with-pgfplots
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y=0:2*pi,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
]

    \addplot3[% 
        contour gnuplot={
            output point meta=rawz,
            number=10,
            labels=false,
        },
        samples=41,
        z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{-1.6},
    ]
        {FunctionE(x,y)};

    \addplot3[surf,samples=25] {FunctionE(x,y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume that is because gnuplot doesn't know that it should also output to the `tempfiles` folder. So maybe it helps -- as you guess this is untested -- when you add `\pgfplotsset{prefix=tempfiles/}` to the preamble, to redirect the gnuplot output to that folder, too.

Comment: @StefanPinnow: Nope, that does not seem to do it. It seems that the `TeX-SE_contourtmp0.dat` and `TeX-SE_contourtmp0.script` files do get written to the `tempfiles/` directory, but the `TeX-SE_contourtmp0.table` is not generated.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that it was not simply `gnuplot` but `contour gnuplot` ... Ok, let's see, if someone else has a solution. Otherwise I will ask Christian (Feuersänger) -- the author of PGFPlots -- for a possible solution.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include#comment481933_206695

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Had not seen that comment before. Am hoping htat mine is the 1/1000. I did not know that you could link to specfic comments like that. How do you get the url for it?

Comment: the "time" that appears after a comment is a URL to the comment so for example your comment above currently says "1 min ago" which links to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358224/using-output-dir-with-gnuplot-fails-to-find-table-file?noredirect=1#comment882377_358224

Comment: You could try to add `cmd= {cd tempfiles & gnuplot \"\script\"}` to your `contour gnuplot` options (if you are on linux replace the & with whatever is used there to combine commands). You could also try to find a working solution with the `file` and the `prefix` key, but imho they and `--output-directory` confuse each other, and like @DavidCarlisle I think that the best is not to use `--output-directory`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That works great. Thanks. Please add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add

```
  cmd= {cd tempfiles & gnuplot \"\script\"}
```

to your `contour gnuplot` options (if you are on linux replace the `&` with whatever is used there to combine commands).

You could also try to find a working solution with the `file` and the `prefix` key, but imho they and `--output-directory` confuse each other.

Like  David Carlisle in his comment I think that the best is not to use `--output-directory`.