# Six-Hump Camel Function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to achieve esthetically the nearest result compared to:

[image]

So far i have only been able to get:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        align =center,
        title = {\textbf{Six-hump camel back function}\\ ${\scriptsize f(x,y)=\left(4-2.1 x_1^2+\frac{x_1^4}{3}\right) x_1^2+x_1 x_2+\left(-4+4 x_2^2\right) x_2^2}$},
        view={310}{30},
        xtick = {2,1,...,-2},
        ytick = {1,0.5,...,-1},
        ztick = {6,5,...,-2},
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=2,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=1,
        zmin=-2,
        zmax=6,
        ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
        grid=major,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$      
            ]
            %some miminum points
            \addplot3[mark=*,red,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] 
        coordinates {(0,0.75,-2)[{\scriptsize A minimum}]};
                
            \addplot3[mark=*,red,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] 
        coordinates {(0,-0.75,-2)[{\scriptsize A minimum}]};

            \addplot3 [
                surf,
                colormap/jet,
                shader=faceted,
                fill opacity=0.75,
                samples=50,
                domain=-2:2,
                y domain=-1:1
                ] {(4-2.1*x^2+x^4/3)*x^2+x*y+(-4+4*y^2)*y^2};

        \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

Thanks for your help

PS: I'm running LaTeX on a Microsoft Windows machine

Comment: I did not check, but this looks similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87900/47927

Comment: Yes i already know but i failed applying it to my case.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to get the colors right with these approaches, I have to admit …

Comment: Oh i don’t care if the colors are the same or not…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87900/47927), you could try with `gnuplot`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            align = center,
            title = {
                \textbf{Six-hump camel back function} \\ 
                $\scriptsize f(x,y) = 
                    \left(4 - 2.1 x_1^2 + \frac{x_1^4}{3}\right) x_1^2 + x_1 
                    x_2 + \left(-4 + 4 x_2^2\right) x_2^2$
                },
            view = {310}{30},
            xtick = {2,1,...,-2},
            ytick = {1,0.5,...,-1},
            ztick = {6,5,...,-2},
            xmin = -2, xmax = 2,
            ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
            zmin = -2, zmax = 6,
            ticklabel style = {
                font = \scriptsize
            },
            grid = major,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$      
        ]

        \addplot3[
            mark=*,
            red,
            draw = none,
            point meta = explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords
        ] coordinates {
            (0,0.75,-2) [{\scriptsize A minimum}]
            (0,-0.75,-2) [{\scriptsize A minimum}]
        };

        \addplot3+[
            no markers,
            raw gnuplot,
            z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{-2}},
        ] gnuplot {
            unset surface;
            set contour base;
            set cntrparam levels 20;
            set isosamples 200;
            set samples 51;
            splot [-2:2][-1:1][-2:6] 
                (4 - 2.1*x^2 + x^4/3)*x^2 + x*y + (-4 + 4*y^2)*y^2;
        };

        \addplot3[
            surf,
            colormap/jet,
            shader = faceted,
            fill opacity = 0.75,
            samples = 51,
            domain = -2:2,
            y domain = -1:1
        ] {(4 - 2.1*x^2 + x^4/3)*x^2 + x*y + (-4 + 4*y^2)*y^2};

        \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Coloring can be done via `contour prepared`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            align = center,
            title = {
                \textbf{Six-hump camel back function} \\ 
                $\scriptsize f(x,y) = 
                    \left(4 - 2.1 x_1^2 + \frac{x_1^4}{3}\right) x_1^2 + x_1 
                    x_2 + \left(-4 + 4 x_2^2\right) x_2^2$
                },
            view = {310}{30},
            xtick = {2,1,...,-2},
            ytick = {1,0.5,...,-1},
            ztick = {6,5,...,-2},
            xmin = -2, xmax = 2,
            ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
            zmin = -2, zmax = 6,
            ticklabel style = {
                font = \scriptsize
            },
            grid = major,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$      
        ]

        \addplot3[
            mark=*,
            red,
            draw = none,
            point meta = explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords
        ] coordinates {
            (0,0.75,-2) [{\scriptsize A minimum}]
            (0,-0.75,-2) [{\scriptsize A minimum}]
        };

        \addplot3+[
            contour prepared,
            contour/labels = false,
            colormap/jet,
            point meta = rawz,
            no markers,
            raw gnuplot,
            z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{-2}},
        ] gnuplot {
            unset surface;
            set contour base;
            set cntrparam levels 20;
            set isosamples 200;
            splot [-2:2][-1:1][-2:6] 
                (4 - 2.1*x^2 + x^4/3)*x^2 + x*y + (-4 + 4*y^2)*y^2;
        };

        \addplot3[
            surf,
            colormap/jet,
            shader = faceted,
            fill opacity = 0.75,
            samples = 51,
            domain = -2:2,
            y domain = -1:1
        ] {(4 - 2.1*x^2 + x^4/3)*x^2 + x*y + (-4 + 4*y^2)*y^2};

        \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With a few additional options, you'll get quite close to the original:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            align = center,
            title = {
                \textbf{Six-hump camel back function} \\ 
                $\scriptsize f(x,y) = 
                    \left(4 - 2.1 x_1^2 + \frac{x_1^4}{3}\right) x_1^2 + x_1 
                    x_2 + \left(-4 + 4 x_2^2\right) x_2^2$
                },
            view = {310}{30},
            xtick = {2,1,...,-2},
            ytick = {1,0.5,...,-1},
            ztick = {6,5,...,-2},
            xmin = -2, xmax = 2,
            ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
            zmin = -2, zmax = 6,
            ticklabel style = {
                font = \scriptsize
            },
            grid = major,
            xlabel = {$x_1$},
            ylabel = {$x_2$},
            zlabel = {$f(x_1,x_2)$},
            axis lines*=left,
            tick align=outside,
            major grid style={
                dotted, gray
            }
        ]

        \addplot3[
            mark=*,
            red,
            draw = none,
            point meta = explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords
        ] coordinates {
            (0,0.75,-2) [{\scriptsize A minimum}]
            (0,-0.75,-2) [{\scriptsize A minimum}]
        };

        \addplot3+[
            contour prepared,
            contour/labels = false,
            colormap/jet,
            point meta = rawz,
            no markers,
            raw gnuplot,
            z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{-2}},
        ] gnuplot {
            unset surface;
            set contour base;
            set cntrparam levels 20;
            set isosamples 200;
            splot [-2:2][-1:1][-2:6] 
                (4 - 2.1*x^2 + x^4/3)*x^2 + x*y + (-4 + 4*y^2)*y^2;
        };

        \addplot3[
            surf,
            colormap/jet,
            shader = flat,
            draw = black,
            samples = 51,
            domain = -2:2,
            y domain = -1:1
        ] {(4 - 2.1*x^2 + x^4/3)*x^2 + x*y + (-4 + 4*y^2)*y^2};

        \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for your help!