Using TikZ to draw a 3D plot with a surface u(x,y), a contour C on the xy-plane and a vertical surface between C and u(x,y)
I want to have a 3D plot to explain integration of a complex function, f(z), along a contour on the complex plane, C. This 3D plot must contain these three ingredients:

A surface plot of a function u(x,y) = Re(f(z)). To simplify matters, any u(x,y) > 0 will do. For example, exp(-(x * x + y * y)).

The contour on the xy-plane, C.

The vertical surface between C and u(x,y). It is a vertical "curtain" whose bottom is the contour C and whose top is at the intersection between u(x,y) and the curtain itself. I want to show this vertical surface because its area is the real part of the integral of f(z) along the contour C.


My knowledge about TikZ is very very limited, but I am eager to learn. The problem is that I have not been able to find an example that could serve as a starting point.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Could you find a picture on the internet, or draw one by hand that shows something similar to what you're looking for? This seems similar, though it lacks the vertical surface it seems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700810/319072

Hi Jasper. Your answer below is just what I asked for. Thanks!

@RamonOliver, Thank you for your feedback. You should consider accepting it if it solved your problem

I collaborated with an AI to develop this code. While I fully grasp the parts I wrote, I haven’t yet delved into the sections the AI generated. Nonetheless, it looks like a promising starting point. Apologies if it’s a bit advanced. I like making tikzpictures for fun.
My apologies to the community if in answering this, I violated any standards. I understand there is no MWE, and the code is advanced. I just thought it was fun to work on.
P.S. Running the calculations on external software is recommended to avoid your computer spending an eternity on compilation.
P.P.S. Let me know if I got anything wrong. I don't know this area of math too well.

Edit: The last version had nested tikzpictures. I remade it in beamer with only one tikzpicture, and also animated it
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import subprocess

polar_angle = 60
azimuthal_angle = 130
highlight_level = 0  # Change this value to select which contour level to draw in red (0-based index)
num_samples = 10  # Change this value to set the number of samples for the red line and rectangles

# Define the function
def my_function(x, y):
    return (np.exp(-((x - 2 * np.cos(0))**2 + (y - 2 * np.sin(0))**2)) +
            2 * np.exp(-((x - 2 * np.cos(120 * np.pi / 180))**2 + (y - 2 * np.sin(120 * np.pi / 180))**2)) +
            3 * np.exp(-((x - 2 * np.cos(240 * np.pi / 180))**2 + (y - 2 * np.sin(240 * np.pi / 180))**2)))

# Create a grid of points
x_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
y_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_vals, y_vals)

# Evaluate the function on the grid
Z = my_function(X, Y)

# Set contour levels
contour_levels = np.linspace(0.1, 2.9, 12)

# Initialize a list to store contour coordinates
contour_coordinates = []
highlight_contours = []

# Define a distance threshold
distance_threshold = 0.1

# Plot contours and collect coordinates
for level_index, level in enumerate(contour_levels):
    contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[level], colors='black')
    for collection in contours.collections:
        for path in collection.get_paths():
            vertices = path.vertices
            if len(vertices) > 1:
                filtered_coords = [vertices[0]]
                for i in range(1, len(vertices)):
                    distance = np.linalg.norm(vertices[i] - vertices[i-1])
                    if distance <= distance_threshold:
                        filtered_coords.append(vertices[i])
                    else:
                        if len(filtered_coords) > 1:
                            contour_coordinates.append(np.array(filtered_coords))
                            if level_index == highlight_level:
                                highlight_contours.append(np.array(filtered_coords))
                        filtered_coords = [vertices[i]]
                if len(filtered_coords) > 1:
                    contour_coordinates.append(np.array(filtered_coords))
                    if level_index == highlight_level:
                        highlight_contours.append(np.array(filtered_coords))

# Generate TikZ code for contours
tikz_code = """\\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.5]
\\clip[tdplot_screen_coords,scale=2] (-3.5,-2.5) rectangle (3.5,2.5);
\\draw[white,tdplot_screen_coords,scale=2] (-3.5,-2.5) rectangle (3.5,2.5); 
"""
for coords in contour_coordinates:
    tikz_code += "\\draw[black]"
    for x, y in coords:
        tikz_code += f"({x:.2f},{y:.2f}) -- "
    tikz_code = tikz_code[:-3] + ";\n"  # Close the contour

# Draw the selected contour level in red and add rectangles
for highlight_contour in highlight_contours:
    highlight_contour = highlight_contour[::num_samples]  # Reduce the number of samples
    tikz_code += "\\draw[red, thick]\n"
    for i in range(len(highlight_contour) - 1):
        x1, y1 = highlight_contour[i]
        x2, y2 = highlight_contour[i + 1]
        tikz_code += f"({x1:.2f},{y1:.2f}) -- "
    tikz_code = tikz_code[:-3] + ";\n"  # Close the red contour line

    # Draw rectangles for each line segment, extending from the base to the height of the function
    for i in range(len(highlight_contour) - 1):
        x1, y1 = highlight_contour[i]
        x2, y2 = highlight_contour[i + 1]
        z1 = my_function(x1, y1)
        z2 = my_function(x2, y2)
        tikz_code += f"""
        \\fill[opacity=0.3,red] ({x1:.2f},{y1:.2f},0) -- ({x2:.2f},{y2:.2f},0) -- ({x2:.2f},{y2:.2f},{z2:.2f}) -- ({x1:.2f},{y1:.2f},{z1:.2f}) -- cycle;
        \\draw[red] ({x1:.2f},{y1:.2f},0) -- ({x2:.2f},{y2:.2f},0) -- ({x2:.2f},{y2:.2f},{z2:.2f}) -- ({x1:.2f},{y1:.2f},{z1:.2f}) -- cycle;
        """

# Generate TikZ code for triangular mesh grid
x_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
y_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)

for i in range(len(x_vals) - 1):
    for j in range(len(y_vals) - 1):
        V1 = (x_vals[i], y_vals[j], my_function(x_vals[i], y_vals[j]))
        V2 = (x_vals[i+1], y_vals[j], my_function(x_vals[i+1], y_vals[j]))
        V3 = (x_vals[i], y_vals[j+1], my_function(x_vals[i], y_vals[j+1]))
        V4 = (x_vals[i+1], y_vals[j+1], my_function(x_vals[i+1], y_vals[j+1]))

        # First triangle
        tikz_code += f"""\\fill[opacity=0.2] ({V1[0]},{V1[1]},{V1[2]}) -- ({V2[0]},{V2[1]},{V2[2]}) -- ({V3[0]},{V3[1]},{V3[2]}) -- cycle;
        \\draw ({V1[0]},{V1[1]},{V1[2]}) -- ({V2[0]},{V2[1]},{V2[2]}) -- ({V3[0]},{V3[1]},{V3[2]}) -- cycle;
        """

        # Second triangle
        tikz_code += f"""\\fill[opacity=0.2] ({V2[0]},{V2[1]},{V2[2]}) -- ({V3[0]},{V3[1]},{V3[2]}) -- ({V4[0]},{V4[1]},{V4[2]}) -- cycle;
        \\draw ({V2[0]},{V2[1]},{V2[2]}) -- ({V3[0]},{V3[1]},{V3[2]}) -- ({V4[0]},{V4[1]},{V4[2]}) -- cycle;
        """

tikz_code += "\\end{tikzpicture}"

preamble = f"""
\\documentclass{{beamer}}
\\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\\usepackage{{tikz,tikz-3dplot}}
\\begin{{document}}
\\begin{{frame}}
\\centering
\\tdplotsetmaincoords{{{polar_angle}}}{{{azimuthal_angle}}}
"""

postscript = f"""
\\end{{frame}}
\\end{{document}}
"""

# Save to a .tex file
with open('TeX_File.tex', 'w') as f:
    f.write(preamble)
    f.write(tikz_code)
    f.write(postscript)


subprocess.run(['lualatex', "TeX_file.tex"])



Thank you for your reply. It fits my needs perfectly. Your code has allowed me to learn a few things, one of them being how to generate TikZ code with Python!

Although I plan to modify your code, how can I acknowledge your help when showing this picture?

@RamonOliver It's really up to you about citation. "Not necessary, but always appreciated"
